# How to Import Excel File to Database with Mapping Laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, database, mapping

Hi i created a demo project that i can with import excel files and get them into my database with laravel excel but what i want to do is with mapping not just a simple import and get them into the database like if the excel file is missing a field or a name i want like to specify each field alone
like field name alone gender alone

here is my code

**Studentsimport.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Student;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;

class StudentsImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow,WithValidation
{
    /**
    * @param Collection $collection
    */
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $data=[
                'name'=>$row['name'],
                'gender'=>$row['gender'],
                'email'=>$row['email_address'],
                'grade'=>$row['grade'],
                'mobile_number'=>$row['mobile_number']
            ];
            Student::create($data);
        }
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return[
            'name'=>'required',
            'gender'=>'required',
            'email_address'=>'required|unique:students,email',
            'grade'=>'required',
            'mobile_number'=>'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

**view.blade.php**

```
<body>
    <h2>Import Excel Data In Laravel</h2>
    @if($errors->any())
        <h5 style="color:red">Following errors exists in your excel file</h5>
        <ol>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{$error}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ol>
    @endif
    <form action="/import" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <input type="file" name="student_file" accept=".xlsx,.xls,.csv" required>
        <br> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    <table border="1" style="margin-top:2em;">
        <thead>
            <tr> 
                <th>S.N.</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Grade</th>
                <th>Email Address</th>
                <th>Mobile Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @php
                $i=0;
            @endphp
            @forelse ($students as $student)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{++$i}}</td>
                    <td>{{$student->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$student->gender}}</td>
                    <td>{{$student->grade}}</td>
                    <td>{{$student->email}}</td>
                    <td>{{$student->mobile_number}}</td>
                </tr>
            @empty
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">No Students</td>
                </tr>
            @endforelse
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

**studentsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Imports\StudentsImport;
use App\Models\Student;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class StudentController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $students = Student::all();
        return view('welcome',compact('students'));
    }
    public function import(Request $req){
        Excel::import(new StudentsImport,$req->file('student_file'));
        return back();
    }
}
```